canvass app : get entities from NN relationship
I'm working on a canvass app. I have a serach text and on click on serach button i want to get all dataverse account records which the serach text is been added to this account from the specility entity. In fact, i have an NN relationship between account and spciality and for example, on the 'AA' account  form i have the specility grid with for example paint .
I want when i fill in in the canvas app search conbobox text the word paint and i click on serach button, to get all th account in the database that have the speciality print in their form. In fact i was thinking about this sentence
Filter( accounts; Account= LookUp(Specialities; Name = TextBoxSearch.Value).Accounts.Account) but unfortunattely it doesn't work it did'nt reconize the specialities entity and even that the account field also . Please help 

